# Question on storing a binary file in the document folder using Salesforce REST API

Tags: apex

I'm working on part of an Apex class to store a retrieved binary file using the REST API to a test folder on Salesforce and I'm not sure exactly how it'll work. I have the Salesforce ID of the test folder, but I'm not sure if it'll require an HTTP POST like this one below:

```
@HttpGet
   public void basicCallout(){
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setMethod('GET');
     req.setEndpoint('callout:/thirdpartyapi/<filepath>');
     req.setHeader("Authorization", "Oauth" + loginResult.getAccessToken());
     HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
     res.setMethod('POST');
     res.setEndpoint('https://na1.salesforce.com/<SalesforceFolderID>');
     }
```

I'm working off the following [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse) as a reference:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already in Apex Code, you can store the document directly:

```
Document doc = new Document(Name=..., Body=res.getBodyAsBlob(), FolderId=...);
insert doc;
```

As a side node, if you did need a second callout, you'd need to create a new HttpRequest, and not modify the HttpResponse `res` as you've done here.

Comment: I see. I'll keep that in mind. Out of curiosity, is there any way to preserve the filename and extension when it's transferred over? To my understanding, HTTPRequest/HTTPResponse commands can only transfer the binary data and not anything else.

Comment: @xorLogic you're right, it's just the binary data. You can use the URL class to decompose the original URL you're calling, but I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: That might work. I'm looking to transfer files between Salesforce and O365. I don't need to preserve the metadata of the files, just the filenames themselves to reference their originals.